# Grouping Sales into non-calendar months

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I am working on a database which includes sales information; the table for this is fairly basic:

ContractID(PK), CustomerID(FK), SalesAgent(FK), Value(int), SalesDate(Date)

And I have a requirement to produce a monthly sales report - sounds simple; group the dates by month.

However, the client has a non-calendar monthly sales structure - effectively, most months are 28 days, December is 42 days, and April & August are 35 days - this means that all months start on a Monday, and the extra weeks are allocated to Easter, High Summer, and Christmas, when business is usually slower.

So effectively I have a calendar like this:

```
Month. StartDate, EndDate
1.  20210104, 20210131
2.  20210201, 20210228
3.  20210301, 20210328
4.  20210329, 20210502
5.  20210503, 20210530
6.  20210531, 20210627
7.  20210628, 20210725
8.  20210726, 20210829
9.  20210830, 20210926
10. 20210927, 20211024
11. 20211025, 20211121
12. 20211122, 20220102
13. 20220103, 20220130
14. 20220131, 20220227   
etc.
```

What's the best way to allocate each sale to a period above to group for reporting - I was initially thinking of having the above table as a CTE within my query, then SELECT based on the SalesDate being before and after the start and End Dates in the above, but what join do I then use to link that to the main query?

Is there no way around this other than to run the query for each specific period as listed above, or can this be done with a UNION?

(hope this makes sense)

Comment: Simply create static custom calendar table (id, year, month, starts_at, ends_at) for reasonable period (up to 2030, for example) and use it as a base. Also you may create stored procedure which generates this calendar temptable for given period or checks/renews static calendar table if it is damaged.

Answer (score 0):

Join your sales data and calendar, template

```
with calendar(Month, StartDate, EndDate) as(
 .. 
)
select ..
from calendar
join sales on sales.date between calendar.StartDate and calendar.EndDate
group by .. calendar.Month ..
```